# Compile error in Hidden Module

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

When I'm trying to do some activity on Macro Enabled sheet I'm facing this problem.

```
Error: Compile error in Hidden Module: SHEET 7
```

Can some one please guide what should be done?

Comment: Could be a number of reasons for this, from a simple typo to a missing reference, to invalid .exd files. Providing the code where the error occurs might help us help you.

Comment: You get that error when your VBA project is password protected. Unprotect you VBA project and then when it errors out, check which line is giving the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The workbook is password protected and I'm unable to open that in order to see the code. Do We need to know the password to UnProtect my VBA Project.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this problem, maybe it also will help you:

go to folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\XLSTART" and make sure there is nothing inside this folder.

In my case is Office12, maybe in your case is Office14 or other numbers, do the same thing, if there is no this folder, you don't care.

Hope it works.